# JRockit Dump File

Tags: dump, jrockit

I need a parameter to start JRockit JVM without (doesn´t metter what happens) generating dump files. Something like -DnoDump or -XXnoJrDump would be great.

Answer (score 3):

The parameter to disable dumps in JRockit is -XXdumpSize:none